# Android options menu is white

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

Faced an issue where my options menu stay's white. I've looked at the documentation and can't really see what I'm doing wrong. Would be good to see another perspective on my code. Thanks. The issue is that the menu created stay's entirely white, the text is usually black. I am able to click on the menu options however and it is functional.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of menu]

main_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/log_out_btn"
        android:title="Log out" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings_btn"
        android:title="Account settings" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/all_users_btn"
        android:title="All users" />

</menu>
```

My MainActivity:

```
package com.david.MyCampusChat;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.devin.MyCampusChat.Fragments.ChatsFragment;
import com.devin.MyCampusChat.Fragments.FriendsFragment;
import com.devin.MyCampusChat.Fragments.RequestsFragment;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    private FirebaseUser fUser;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    //Fragments.
    private ChatsFragment chatsFragment;
    private FriendsFragment friendsFragment;
    private RequestsFragment requestsFragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabLayout  = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager  = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        fAuth      = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mToolbar   = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        //fragments
        chatsFragment    = new ChatsFragment();
        friendsFragment  = new FriendsFragment();
        requestsFragment = new RequestsFragment();

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MyCampus Chats");

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new MainActivity.ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 0);
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(chatsFragment, "Chats");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(friendsFragment, "Friends");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(requestsFragment, "Requests");
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        fUser = fAuth.getCurrentUser();

        //Check to see if the current user is null or not, if so, they are not logged in.
        if(fUser == null){
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    /** Creates the options menu **/
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** Gets the options selected from the menu resource **/
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
         super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

            switch(item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.log_out_btn:
                    fAuth.signOut();
                    sendToStart();

                    break;
                case R.id.all_users_btn:
                case R.id.settings_btn:
            }

         return true;
    }

    /** Simply sends the user to the startActivity (state not logged in) **/
    private void sendToStart(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String>   fragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();


        public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
            super(fm, behavior);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            fragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you should check your style.xml file. the options menu behaviour is affected by a particular style. if you don't mind add the code of your style.xml file. this will go a long way in helping you fix this

Answer (score 0):

Add following line to your theme in `styles.xml`:

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/your_color</item>
```

your_color -> whatever the color you choose from the `color.xml`